# DirectX COM Object Creation Overhead

Tags: c++, performance, com, directx

When I'm creating a DirectX Buffer or any other "large" COM object, I'm wary of calling the "CreateBuffer" et al. functions every frame as I'm sure there is a significant overhead for creating such objects.

My question is, does this apply to all of the DirectX COM Objects? For example, is creating a RasterizerState object particularly expensive and should I keep calling the "CreateRasterizerState" function to a minimum (i.e. not every frame)? I know that COM is a way of wrapping objects in a uniform interface that can be called from many languages, so surely creating a RasterizerState (which I imagine require less memory and processor time to create than a Buffer, say) wouldn't have the same overhead as creating a Buffer so could be done more often, without causing a drop in performance. Or should I just try and reuse these objects as much as possible?

Many thanks for any insight you can give.

Comment: As a general rule you should aim to minimize DirectX API calls as much as possible.

Comment: Many API calls could be expensive, but generally, creating COM objects is not. Unless you use `CoCreateInstance` (which isn't used for directx), creating a COM object is equivalent to an ordinary `new object()`.

Comment: As I see it, any programmer-side overhead such as COM, allocation, virtual calls, even stuff inside API etc. is negligibly low, if we compare it with a gory messy stuff that's going on in driver's guts and which is hidden from us. General rule is that you must call `Create*()` functions as rare as possible: it almost always leads to *CPU-GPU synchronization points*. Reuse your resources: overwrite it, forecast and create it bigger if need to grow often, change it if possible, but only create it from scratch if there's no other way. Surely, you must accurately profile before any optimizations.